# Convertir un textarea a Integer en Java

Tags: java, jframe, integer

Tengo diseñado en Netbeans un JFrame de Java. Tengo 4 botones y quiero que cada botón tenga una función. Que el Botón 1 sume, que el 2 reste, que el 3 multiplique y que el 4 divida. Además, tengo 2 text areas, para colocar los números que posteriormente van a ser procesados. Necesitaría saber cómo darle la función a cada botón.

Para los botones tengo esto, en este caso el de sumar:
(`Lblresul` es un Jlabel)

```
int Suma;
    int a = Integer.parseInt(Text1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText());
    Suma=a+b;
    Lblresul = IntegerSuma;
```

El error me dice que `Lblresul = IntegerSuma;` no es válido. Que int no puede ser convertido a Jlabel. Qué se hace en este caso?
Saludos! Espero la Respuesta

Comment: Si muestras algo del código podría intentar ayudar, pero lo que deberias poner dentro del `int a = Integer.parseInt()` sería coger el id o el nombre del text area y usar la función que tiene para obtener el texto que contiene dentro, pongamos que el text area se llama `input1`, pues tendrás que poner `input1.getText()` lo que se quedaría así : `int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText())`

Comment: Para esto no tiene mucho caso usar JTextArea, deberías usar JTextField.

Comment: @amtamv El problema es que no tengo código, lo único que tengo es lo que viene predeterminado cuando creas los botones y las textareas. Serían como 100 líneas.

Comment: @Sal Cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: @Inkinvissible pues entonces haz lo que te he comentado, los campos de textos tienen funciones para poder obtener el texto que has metido dentro, ahora sería usar la función para hacer un parseInt y ya estaría.

En cuanto a lo comentado por @Sal la diferencia mas clara es que un `JtextField` es para texto en una sola linea, lo cual para lo tuyo sería lo mas útil y el `TextArea` suele ser para múltiples líneas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Mirá, lo que he hecho hasta ahora                               
 `public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(Text1.getText());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(Text2.getText());
        
    }`

Comment: JTextArea se usa principalmente cuando necesitas capturar varias líneas, mientras quieres parsear números que no llevan caracter de nueva línea.

Comment: Lo que me faltaría serían los botones...

Comment: @Inkinvissible En cuanto a los botones, lo suyo es que cuando el usuario haga click en el de suma, obtenga los campos de int a y int b, haga el calculo y muestre el resultado. Básicamente sería lo que tienes el el `Public NewJFrame`, pero en el evento de click button.

Comment: Ahora la pregunta es... Cómo hago para poner el resultado en el Label? Tengo `Lblresul = IntegerSuma;`, pero no es válido.

Comment: ¿Qué es Lblresul? ¿un JLabel? Si es así, mira los métodos de JLabel para modificar el texto

Comment: Sí, disculpá. Lblresul es un JLabel.

Comment: @PabloLozano dónde puedo consultar lo métodos?

Comment: Tu idea es que al hacer click muestre el resultado o se guarde en algún sitio

Comment: Lo muestre al resultado. Lo que hice fue: `Lblresul.setText(String.valueOf(Suma));` Esto es en el caso de la suma. Qué opinan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ver si así te es mas cómodo o mas útil. He creado de forma rapida un mini programa que la idea suya sería solo la suma, tu en tu caso sería reutilizar los input y manejar los botones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez tienes tu diseño, vas al botón de sumar y haces clic derecho y en `eventos -> Mouse -> Mouse Clicked`. De forma automática te llevara a la clase que se encarga de ello, una vez dentro de ella, sería tan simple como lo siguiente (Eso si, no hay comprobaciones ni nada en el mío, lo suyo es añadirlas con un try and catch o como tu quieras para controlar los errores).

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText());
    txtResultado.setText(Integer.toString(a+b));
    
}
```

El `txtResultado` es un Label el cual mostrara el resultado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Te puedo molestar por otra pregunta?

Comment: Si claro, dime y te intento ayudar

Comment: En caso de que el usuario trate de dividir por 0, ¿como hago para que salga un cartel que diga que no se puede dividir por 0?

Comment: Pues sería hacer lo que te he comentado arriba, sería usar el Try y que pruebe a hacer la parte del código y el catch para que realice el mensaje que deseas, En el caso del catch sería usar `ArithmeticException`, ya que el catch cuando detecte que es una excepción aritmética, el cartel sería poniendo `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"NO SE PUEDE DIVIDIR POR 0","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`

Comment: Perfecto!!! Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda! Un genio!! Que tengas un buen día!

Comment: Igualmente, que tengas un buen día

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128213/discussion-between-inkinvissible-and-amtamv).

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo, sin necesidad de recurrir a excepciones:
`private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    int a = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(input2.getText());
    if (b != 0)
         txtResultado.setText(Integer.toString(a+b));
    else
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "División por cero no permitida","Error aritmético", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}`

Comment: @TomuRain La solución también es útil, pero la idea de la excepción no es solamente que se encargue de la división, si no de que luego añadas otro mismo Catch con `Exception`, ya que si el usuario pone una string o pone algo que no concuerda con lo que tu deseas, puedas controlar el error y no se rompa el código o cualquier otra cosa. Así si pusieras en b o en A la string "hola" puedas mandar otro JOptionPane que diga a que se debe el error.