# Como realizar una sumatoria de varios jformattedtextfield

Tags: java, netbeans

Buen día, tengo tres jformattedtextfield en netbeans, los cuales están configurados con el FormatterFactory como integer, para que me los separe por miles, ahora no se como hacer para realizar una sumatoria de los mismos. Desde ya les agradezco por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Convertir un textarea a Integer en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/474922/convertir-un-textarea-a-integer-en-java)

Comment: Tienes parte del codigo? pero en e general te recomiendo que extraigas lo ingresado en el textField con un .getText() eso lo conviertes a string .getText().toString() y luego a ese string le haces un parseInt para hacer un cast a Int te quedaria algo como
int sum = Integer.parseInt(textFiled.getText().toString());